# How to add Basic authentication in springfox swagger2

Tags: spring-security, swagger, spring-security-oauth2, swagger-2.0, springfox

Currently the swagger UI is exposed without any security scheme.
Need to implement basic auth for the swagger UI. So that everytime its pops for username and password before displaying the UI.

I have implemented ApiKey authorization but not able to configure for BasicAuth .

Very new to spring